# error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]|

Tags: c++

I try to make little program for learn C++ but I don't understand why that don't work and I find nothing to help me :

```
D:\000-Mes Documents\Programmation\C++\OpenClassromms_8\main.cpp|30|error: expression list treated as compound expression in initializer [-fpermissive]|
```

main.cpp :

```
#include <iostream>
#include "fct_tabl.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //initialisation des variable
    double const version(0.001); //version du logiciel
    int nbrNotes /* Nombre de Notes */ ;

    //En tête du programe
    cout << "================= Arodia OpenClassrooms Moyenne (AOCM v" << version << ") =================" << endl << "Bienvenue dans le logiciel de calcule de moyenne de la suite Arodia OpenClassrooms." << endl << endl ;

    //Affectation du nombre de notes
    do
    {
        cout << "Combien de notes voulez-vous entrer ? " ;
        cin >> nbrNotes;
    } while (nbrNotes < 1);

    //Avertissement
    cout << endl << "AVERTISSEMENT : Vos notes doivent etre sur le meme coeficient et sur un maximum identique." << endl << endl ;

    //Création du tableau des notes
    int const nbrTabl(nbrNotes);
    double note[nbrTabl];

    //Appel de la fonction pour entrer les valeurs dans le tableau
    double moyenne(note[nbrTabl],nbrNotes);

    return 0;
}
```

fct_table.h

```
#ifndef FCT_TABL_H_INCLUDED
#define FCT_TABL_H_INCLUDED

double moyenne(double tabl[],int nbrVal);

#endif // FCT_TABL_H_INCLUDED
```

fct_tabl.cpp

```
#include "fct_tabl.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

double moyenne(double tabl[],int nbrVal)
{
    for(int i(0);i++;i<nbrVal)
    {
        cout << "Note " << i << " : ";
        cin >> tabl[i];
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I know, that prog isn't finish, I see error when I try before finish.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably want

```
double ma_moyenne = moyenne(note, nbrNotes);
```

instead of

```
double moyenne(note[nbrTabl],nbrNotes);
```

Comment: Or just `moyenne(note, nbrNotes);`. The return value is (a) meaningless, and (b) unused. Furthermore the loop in that function is nonsense.